# Grub not loading

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2

About a month ago I installed ubuntu 14.04 on my computer. I did not replace the Windows 8 that I was previously using. While ubuntu has by and large been working very well, one issue is that grub does not load when I restart my computer. If I want to switch operating systems, I have to restart my computer and then go into the BIOS and switch the boot mode from CSM to UEFI (or vice-versa).

While it is not the end of the world to have to do this, it would be more convenient for me to have grub. Also, I am planning to install another Linux distro in the near feature, and without grub working I am worried that I won't be able to switch between my Linux distros.

Does anyone have any suggestions for getting grub to work?

Comment: I had a similar problem last month, however I also had no gui which made the problem tougher. I did get grub working using a tutorial. While I don't have that link, I do have a link that should fix your grub using a graphical tool. http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/ I hope that helps

Comment: Try running `sudo grub-install` and `sudo update-grub` if you haven't already. And could you post the output of these commands and the contents of `/etc/default/grub`? Also, sometime Windows CHKDSK corrupts the boot partition

Comment: `sudo grub-install` doesn't work; I'm prompted to specify an install device.

Comment: I read somewhere that you have to decide on either UEFI or compatible (CSM) mode _before_ installing, as the OS will only be able to work with the configuration it had when it was installed. So if you used different settings to install your two systems, it looks bad. This does not have to be true, but I am pretty sure. It is the same for hard disks in SATA or legacy IDE mode.

Comment: @AlessandroPower first update GRUB from live cd as `update-grub` then in your BIOS enable Legacy also and just when your system is booting press [esc]key and choose boot options as Ubuntu now you will see GRUB

Answer (score 0):

If you follow [this, unfortunately german instructions](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/EFI_Nachbearbeitung), it might work.

So first you have to install some packages, namely `linux-signed-generic  grub-efi-amd64-signed  shim-signed`. This will install the signed kernel, your old kernel will be kept and works as a fallback if you boot with EFI disabled.

After that, update grub by running `sudo grub-install --uefi-secure-boot`. If you get an error message, run it with `sudo grub-install --uefi-secure-boot --force`.

After that, your system should boot in both BIOS modes. Please not that installing a new kernel while the system is booted in CSM or legacy mode, the relevant package `linux-signed-generic` will be removed and you have to repeat the steps above.

Comment: Unfortunately I received an error after running `sudo grub-install --uefi-secure-boot --force`: `grub-install: error: install device is not specified.`

Comment: For the package installation, did you want me to just run `sudo apt-get install linux-signed-generic` and `sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64-signed shim-signed`?

Comment: Yes, `sudo apt-get install linux-signed-generic grub-efi-amd64 shim-signed` is correct, as long as you have a 64-bit system, of course.

I made a mistake, I am sorry. `grub-install` expects a device, so assuming you only have one harddrive, the command would be `sudo grub-install --uefi-secure-boot /dev/sda`.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work either. I was only able to boot Windows in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems when I installed Ubuntu on my lap(the UEFI mode was on). Someone told me to uninstall Ubuntu and reinstall it after disabling UEFI. Needless to say that sure did work. You said you installed it before one month, I believe the problem didn't came to exist just now. If there is still time for reinstall try that one too.

Comment: I may try this in the future, but I do not have any immediate plans to reinstall ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help but have you tryed using the disk to repair grub?
I'm sorry if this sounds basic but this has helped me with a problem sorta similar

Answer (score 0):

You can boot Ubuntu only in UEFI because you have installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode while Your windows installation is in Legacy (Not EFI) Mode.

To Avoid Such issues you need to Install Ubuntu in UEFI mode only if Windows is installed in UEFI mode or Ubuntu is the only operating system on your computer. If your windows is installed in Legacy mode, then you must install Ubuntu in Legacy mode.

To solve this issue you need to convert Ubuntu from UEFI mode to Legacy mode. 
Please follow below instructions to do it.

1) Start Boot-Repair, click on **Advanced options**, go to the  **GRUB location** tab.

2) Untick the **Separate /boot/efi partition** option & Click the **Apply** button.

[image]

3) Set up your BIOS so that it boots the HDD in Legacy mode

That's it.

Comment: Actually my Windows is installed in UEFI mode while ubuntu is installed in Legacy mode. How would that change your instructions?

Comment: If Ubuntu is installed in Legacy mode, then you don't have to change BIOS setting to load Grub from Legacy to UEFI.

Comment: Step 2 produces the following error: `GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.
Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.`

Comment: You need to create small partition for bios boot. Use Ubuntu 14.04 live DVD and Gparted tool to create it. Assign partition bios_grub, apply changes and repeat Step 2.